# Jasmine: can you approximate normal setTimeout behavior?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

```
it("shows an alert", function(done) {
    function showAlert() {
        alert("hello");
        expect(true).toBe(true);
        done();
    }
    setTimeout(showAlert, 200);
});
```

When I run this test in a browser, it does not display an alert. Further, I get the message `Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)`. If I add the line `jasmine.clock().tick(500);`, having installed the clock, it works. As I (don't fully) understand it, Jasmine sort of hijacks setTimeout. I actually want it to wait 0.2 seconds of real time.
If that's actually impossible, I'm wondering if I can still test asynchronous, vanilla JavaScript functions that don't involve promises or AJAX with Jasmine 3.2.1. I know about how long they'll take, and I'm not worried about how long it takes to run the test suite.

(Some of my functions have callbacks, but they aren't working in this context despite working elsewhere, and not all of them need callbacks.)

Answer (score 0):

Ahah... I removed `jasmine.clock().install();` from `beforeEach()` and `jasmine.clock().uninstall();` from `afterEach()`, and then it worked as expected. I put those statements in while experimenting with the Clock class and then totally forgot they were there. Evidently Clock does, in fact, hijack queued JavaScript timeouts.